# C# - Setting XML Node values as Stings from StreamReader result

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, streamreader

I'm using an API call to return some XML data from a web server. The XML data is in the following format:

```
<forismatic>
    <quote>
        <quoteText>The time you think you're missing, misses you too.</quoteText>               
        <quoteAuthor>Ymber Delecto</quoteAuthor>
        <senderName></senderName>
        <senderLink></senderLink>
        <quoteLink>http://forismatic.com/en/55ed9a13c0/</quoteLink>
    </quote>
</forismatic>
```

I can retrieve the raw XML data successfully, and I want to add the `<quoteText>`and `<quoteAuthor>` node values to strings but seem to be unable to do this. My current code:

```
    private void btnGetQuote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/");                            
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string reqString = "method=getQuote&key=457653&format=xml&lang=en";
        byte[] reqData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);
        req.ContentLength = reqData.Length;

        using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
            reqStream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);

        using (WebResponse res = req.GetResponse())
        using (Stream resSteam = res.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resSteam))
        {
            string xmlData = sr.ReadToEnd();
            txtXmlData.Text = xmlData;
            Read(xmlData);
        }
    }

    private void Read(string xmlData)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
        string quote = doc.Element("quote").Attribute("quoteText").Value;
        string auth = doc.Element("quote").Attribute("quoteAuthor").Value;
        txtQuoteResult.Text = "QUOTE: " + quote + "\r\n" + "AUTHOR: " + auth;                    
    }
```

My program bombs out with **An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred** while trying to set the string value `quote`. I've looked at some similar posts and made various changes but can't seem to get the two string values set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use `doc.Element("quote")` - there's no such element, so that's returning null. You'd want `doc.Root.Element("quote")`. Next you're asking for `quoteText` and `quoteAuthor` as if they were attributes - they're not, they're elements too.

So basically you want:

```
private void Read(string xmlData)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
    XElement quote = doc.Root.Element("quote");
    string text = quote.Element("quoteText").Value;
    string author = quote.Element("quoteAuthor").Value;
    txtQuoteResult.Text = $"QUOTE: {text}\r\nAUTHOR: {author}";
}
```

(I'd personally make the method *return* the string value and set it as `txtQuoteResult.Text` within the calling method, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: That's great, tanks so much! Ran a test and it's working a treat. I'm still getting to grips with XML and working out nodes/attributes/elements. :)